# C - Double Pointer Struct inside a Struct Array Dereference

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, dereference

I am having trouble trying to dereference a double pointer to an array of structs.

The struct is defined:

```
struct node_list_t {
     struct node_t **node_ptr;
};
```

I have done the following to allocate memory and initialize values:

```
struct node_t *nodeArray;
struct node_list_t *mainList = (struct node_list_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct node_list_t));

nodeArray =(struct node_t*)malloc(10 * sizeof(struct node_t));
for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
    nodeArray[i].mass = i;
}

mainList->node_ptr = &nodeArray;
```

Since we are being required to use a double pointer I am trying the following unsuccessfully to dereference as such:

```
printf("%f\n",mainList->node_ptr[i]->mass);
```

We are forced to keep node_ptr as a double pointer, so I cannot change that. How would I dereference this? Thanks.

Comment: That would be `printf("%f\n",(*mainList->node_ptr)[i].mass);`

Comment: why did you remove your code? Could you revert it back, otherwise the answer doesn't make sense in regards to the question.

Comment: Please do not sabotage your own question.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that would be

```
printf("%f\n",(*mainList->node_ptr)[i].mass);
```

Why? `mainList->node_ptr` is double pointer to `struct node_t`.

`*mainList->node_ptr` dereference the double pointer and you get a single pointer to `struct node_t`: the pointer returned from the second `malloc`.

So `(*mainList->node_ptr)[i].mass` is equivalent to

```
struct node_t *nodes = *mainList->node_ptr;
// nodes[0] is the first node, nodes[1] the second, etc.
nodes[i].mass;
```

**edit**

When you have trouble finding the correct dereference in one line, do it step by step like in my example above. Then it is much easier to rewrite it in one line.

**edit 2**

Since the OP removed the code from the question, this answer makes no sense
without it, this was the original code:

> ```
> struct node_list_t {
>      struct node_t **node_ptr;
> };
> ```
>
> I have done the following to allocate memory and initialize values:
>
> ```
> struct node_t *nodeArray;
> struct node_list_t *mainList = (struct node_list_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct node_list_t));
>
> nodeArray =(struct node_t*)malloc(10 * sizeof(struct node_t));
> for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
>     nodeArray[i].mass = i;
> }
>
> mainList->node_ptr = &nodeArray;
> ```